# [elasticsearch-image]plugin install error

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a problem when installing plugin(elasticsearch-image).

script :  bin/plugin install kiwionly/elasticsearch-image/2.4.1 
error: Could not find plugin descriptor 'plugin-descriptor.properties' in plugin zip
(plugin : https://libraries.io/github/kiwionly/elasticsearch-image)

Do you know why above error is happend?
How can i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to clone the github repo and build the plugin yourself. There is no binary download. You tried to download the source and install it as a plugin, which does not work.